# Prediction From Loaded Model | DistributedException

Tags: python, h2o

There may be an obvious solution to this, as we're new to the H2O platform, though we've been unable to find any conclusive information.

We're saving our (H2O-XGBoost) models via Python:

```
h2o.save_model(model=model, path=/path/to/our/models, force=True)
```

Then subsequently loading our models (loaded after starting the server cleanly if that matters):

```
model = h2o.load_model("/path/to/our/models/modelname")
```

From here the model looks good and is loaded within the Flow UI.

We load our prediction frame:

```
pf = h2o.H2OFrame(python_obj=data_list, destination_frame='PREDICTION_FRAME', header=-1)
```

We attempt to make a prediction against the prediction frame we just loaded:

```
model.predict(pf)
```

Error Message (same result within Flow UI & Python):

```
ERROR MESSAGE:

DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'null'

 (water.util.DistributedException)
  DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
      water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:478)
      water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:486)
      water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:390)
      water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:396)
      hex.Model.predictScoreImpl(Model.java:1280)
      hex.Model.score(Model.java:1145)
      water.api.ModelMetricsHandler.predict(ModelMetricsHandler.java:420)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)
      water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:451)
      water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:296)
      water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:222)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
      org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
      org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
      org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
      org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
      org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
  Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
      hex.tree.xgboost.XGBoostModel.score0(XGBoostModel.java:462)
      hex.Model.score0(Model.java:1432)
      hex.Model$BigScore.map(Model.java:1377)
      water.MRTask.compute2(MRTask.java:657)
      water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute1(H2O.java:1266)
      hex.Model$BigScore$Icer.compute1(Model$BigScore$Icer.java)
      water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1262)
      jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
      jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
      jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
      jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
      jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

If we do not load the saved model and just build it on the fly, predictions work fine on the same prediction frame. So, it's something to do with using a saved model it seems.

My initial thought was the frames used for training and validation for the model in question needed to be present, so I exported those and imported them along with the saved model, but received the same error.

Some relevant information:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12

H2O Build git branch    master
H2O Build git hash  7cb70c6a5909257868f72f87da27c07670837f09
H2O Build git describe  jenkins-master-4171-1-g7cb70c6-dirty
H2O Build project version   3.17.0.99999
H2O Build age   8 days
H2O Built by    root
H2O Built on    2018-01-13 13:26:13
H2O Internal Security   Disabled
Flow version    0.7.12

getCloud
56ms    
H2O_from_python_root_e9226d
CLOUD STATUS
HEALTHY CONSENSUS LOCKED
Version Started Nodes (Used / All)
3.17.0.99999    a few seconds ago   1 / 1
NODES
Show advanced
    Name    Ping    Cores   Load    My CPU %    Sys CPU %   GFLOPS  Memory Bandwidth    Data (Used/Total)   Data (% Cached) GC (Free / Total / Max) Disk (Free / Max)   Disk (% Free)
127.0.0.1:54321 a few seconds ago   24  0.080   5   5   NaN - / s   - / NaN undefined   NaN%    17.76 GB / NaN undefined / 17.78 GB 53.26 GB / 109.88 GB    48%
TOTAL   -   24  0.080   -   -   NaN - / s   - / NaN undefined   NaN%    17.76 GB / NaN undefined / 17.78 GB 53.26 GB / 109.88 GB    48%
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4585?filter=21100) with XGBoost models in H2O, and is currently scheduled to be fixed in the next major release of H2O, v3.18 (there's already a [pull request](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/1971/files) with a fix).  It does not affect any other types of models in H2O.